# Objective -c: String length from instancetype

Tags: ios, objective-c

Very new to Objective c. My interface and implementation looks like this:

```
// MyAuth.h
// @interface
+ (instancetype)sharedToken;

// MyAuth.m
//@implementation
+ (instancetype)sharedToken {
   static MyAuth *_sharedToken = nil;
   static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
   dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
       _sharedToken = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"token"];
   });
   return _sharedToken;
}
```

Now I'm trying to get the length of the `sharedToken` but am stuck here. What I've tried

`[MyAuth sharedToken].length // doesn't work`

How can I get the length of `sharedToken

Comment: So the class is called `MyAuth` or `JXAppAPIClient`?

Comment: This is very confused. What is the kind of object you're getting out of the user defaults? Is it a string?

Comment: @Wain sorry, typo. It's MyAuth.

Comment: @JoshCaswell Yes, a string

Comment: So is `MyAuth` an `NSString` subclass? Or why are you trying to put a string into a `MyAuth` pointer?

Comment: @JoshCaswell Thx for your patience. I'm very new to Obj C. I'm trying to use `_sharedToken` (which I'm using as a string) throughout my app but maybe I'm going about this the wrong way(?)

Comment: Why is the `sharedToken` method setup to return a type of `instancetype`? It shouldn't be. That should only be used by `init` methods or convenience methods that return an actual instance of the class in question. This method returns something other than `MyAuth` instances (or their derivatives). The method should return `NSString` if that is what your `_sharedToken` is and what your calling code expects.

Comment: FYI - do not use `valueForKey:` with `NSUserDefaults`. Use `objectForKey:`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want a string pulled from `NSUserDefaults` to be accessible everywhere in your app, via this method.

The return type of the method needs to be the type of the object you're actually returning:

```
+ (NSString *)sharedToken;
```

`instancetype` says that the method returns an instance of the class which runs the method.

The pointer you use for the string should also have the correct type:

```
static NSString *_sharedToken = nil;
```

Now the compiler will let you send `length` to the result of the method call.